# Why bean is circular autowiring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm writting some REST API app and I faced with problem when bean autowires by himself. Idk what can cause this error because class UserRepositoryImpl doesn't have fields with his own datatype. Only interface and simple component bean

**1st class**

```
@Repository
    public class UserRepositoryImpl {

private final UserRepository repository;

private final UserDomainConverter converter;

@Autowired
public UserRepositoryImpl(UserRepository repository,
                          UserDomainConverter converter) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.converter = converter;
}


//some methods
}
```

**2nd class**

```
@Component
public class UserDomainConverter {

//some methods
}
```

**3rd class**

```
    @Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
    Optional<UserEntity> findByAuthToken(String authToken);

Optional<UserEntity> findByNickname(String nickname);

List<UserEntity> findUserEntitiesByIdIn(List<Long> idList);

List<UserEntity> findUserEntitiesByNicknameIn(String nickname);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2022-09-14 23:56:06.379  INFO 21408 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-09-14 23:56:06.387  INFO 21408 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-09-14 23:56:06.403 ERROR 21408 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   userController defined in file [D:\IdeaProjects\sigma-internship\target\classes\spotylike\spotylike\controller\UserController.class]
      ↓
   userService defined in file [D:\IdeaProjects\sigma-internship\target\classes\spotylike\spotylike\service\UserService.class]
┌─────┐
|  userRepositoryImpl defined in file [D:\IdeaProjects\sigma-internship\target\classes\spotylike\spotylike\repository\impl\UserRepositoryImpl.class]
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It would be nice if you shared your code, instead of simply the class stubs.

Comment: Are you sure your `UserRepositoryImpl` doesn't actually `implements UserRepository` ? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're stumbling across Spring Data JPA's repository implementation lookup mechanism. You can read a bit more in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html#repositoryImplementationPostfix--) but I think you'll get around it by renaming your class to something that doesn't end with `Impl` if you don't want to mess with the `@EnableJpaRepositories`-annotation.

Comment: Thank you! I renamed interface into UserRepo and UserRepositoryImpl into UserRepository

Answer (score 0):

I thing you dont need to autowire the constructor of UserRepositoryImpl because the class has the reposotry-anotation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).